# Archive submission failed with errors

Tags: xcode, swift

[image]when i try to submit my app on the last process i get this how do you fix this. This is a Spritkit game and I'm not using any storyboards that you can visually see like in UIKIT because in making a game.

[image]

Comment: For future reference, try using Shift-Command-3 for a whole screenshot or Shift-Command-4 for a partial one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go into the general settings for you main target and make sure that storyboard is set in there:

[image]

After reading your comments I can see that you are using sprite kit and have deleted your main storyboard. To fix this issue make a new project using sprite kit and take the main storyboard from that and put it into this project. Then you'll be able to select it.

Comment: what if its not and all i see is launchscreen can i type it in.

Comment: Yeah, either use the drop down menu or start typing it in

Comment: ok its still not working I'm going to add a picture up top of what it looks like

Comment: Clean your project and try again

Comment: What is the name of your storyboard?

Comment: I'm not even using a storyboard though I'm in SpritKit

Comment: I have GameScene (the first one)

Comment: Then SecondScene (the second one and these are all SKscenes

Comment: Oh thanks I think the link make sense early I delete main story board because I dodnt know you need it so now I'm going into another project and pulling that one

Comment: That should fix you're issue. I will update my answer to contain this info

Comment: Thanks So So So much!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to make a new storyboard if you don't plan on using it. If you wish to use a storyboard use Swinny89's answer, if you don't wish to use the storyboard you can override didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in your app delegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch with your first view controller
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    self.window =
        [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

You will also need to blank out your main interface in your general settings.

[image: blank out main interface]